# delete a row in table

Tags: android, sqlite

im trying to delete one row from the table, which has a specific timeday,  here is the function i wrote to do so in my dbhelper:

```
public void deleteLesson (String timeday) 
              { 
                 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
                 db.delete("Lessons",  
                 "'" +timeday+ "' = ? ",  
                 new String[] {timeday}); 
              }
```

but this code deletes all of the data from database!
can any one tell me what is the problem?

Comment: What is your column name?

Comment: you wrote something like delete from Lessons where 1 = 1 (I mean '<timeday>' = '<timeday>'). Then it deletes all from table Lessons.

Comment: @shree.pat18 the column name is timeday too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'timeday'` in single quotes is a string literal. Comparing it to a literal of the same value is true for all rows in the database.

You probably wanted to write something like

```
db.delete("Lessons",  
             "timeday = ? ",  
             new String[] {timeday});
```

where the `timeday` inside the SQL is the column name.